# A simple way to print an incomplete TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, subdividing

I would like to print a table of contents after each part of a book class document. This toc will show only the contents of the relevant part.

I could use the `minitoc` package but (1.) it primary intended to print toc after each chapter (not part) and (2.) it seems a very complex and heavy package (800 pages of doc) which modifies deeply titles formating.

So, I'm looking to a easier way to do this simple request. A solution which does not change the layout or fonts characteristics is preferable. In fact, I just want a way to use the classic `\tableofcontents` command several times *but* in order to show only the part 1, and then the part 2, 3, ... .

Comment: Actually the documentation is just 200 pages, the rest is irrelevant material.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simulate this behavior with the `titletoc` package.

At the beginning of each `\part`, issue a `\startcontents` command and at the end a `\stopcontents` command.

After that, start a new `\chapter*` and then issue a `\printcontents` command.

Having a look at the following MWE clarifies these things:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\startcontents[first]
\part{1st part}
\chapter{1st}
\section{A section}
\chapter{2nd}
\section{A section}
\chapter{3rd}
\section{A section}
\stopcontents[first]
\chapter*{\contentsname\markboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
\printcontents[first]{}{0}{}

\startcontents[second]
\part{2nd part}
\chapter{1st}
\section{A section}
\chapter{2nd}
\section{A section}
\chapter{3rd}
\section{A section}
\stopcontents[second]
\chapter*{\contentsname\markboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
\printcontents[second]{}{0}{}

\end{document}
```

ToC of the first part

[image]

and Toc of the second part

[image]

Comment: Thanks. For my good knowledge, could you explain `\contentsname\markboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}`? Why using `markboth` like it's called automatically by each chapter?

Comment: @ppr `\contentsname` expands to the name of the Table of Contents in your language. Note that `\markboth` is not issued by starred chapters (`\chapter*`), so if you don't add this you will have the headers of the previous starred chapter.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with the following mark-up:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}

\part{1st part}
\invisiblelocaltableofcontents \label{toc:part1}
\chapter{1st}
\section{A section}
\chapter{2nd}
\section{A section}
\chapter{3rd}
\section{A section}

\tableofcontents\ref{toc:part1}

\part{2nd part}
\invisiblelocaltableofcontents \label{toc:part2}

\chapter{1st}
\section{A section}
\chapter{2nd}
\section{A section}
\chapter{3rd}
\section{A section}

\tableofcontents \ref{toc:part2}

\end{document}
```

The TOC of Part 1:

[image: toc part 1]

The TOC of Part 2:

[image: toc part 2]

Comment: How might I show these parts "at the beginning", rather than having to leave them to the end?

Comment: Also does not seem to apply to the starred version (un-numbered version)...